# Reactjs JSX cannot be rendered under GKE

Tags: reactjs, google-kubernetes-engine

I was working on a Reactjs web application. Under src/static/js folder I have a file named main.jsx. Inside this file, I have a code block

```
(async () => {
const response = await fetch('/config');
// const response = await fetch(process.env.PUBLIC_URL + `/config`);
const body = await response.json();

window.APP_CONFIG = body;

// Use the ReactDOM.render to show your component on the browser
ReactDOM.render(
    <App/>,
    rootElement
)
})();
```

It seems working fine in local environment, and even Heroku. However, after I deployed to GKE, the above code does not work. It cannot load the config which is inside a content.yaml file. Please give me advices.

The problem can be reproduced by following this guide https://reshamas.github.io/deploying-deep-learning-models-on-web-and-mobile/ and running on GKE (Google Cloud).

Comment: How did you create this cluster using GUI or CLI? In this docs I can see that its required `Any cloud platform (such as Paperspace or AWS) is usable, as long as a GPU is available.` Did you add GPU Nvidia Tesla P100 with 100 GB of storage? It's not set as default so you would need to set it manually.

Comment: For GKE I used GUI. Howver, I deployed on Heroku without GPU, and it worked fine.

Comment: Have you tried to use cluster with GPU Nvidia Tesla P100 and 100 GB of storage as was mentioned in tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

As it was mentioned in the [guide link](https://reshamas.github.io/deploying-deep-learning-models-on-web-and-mobile/) provided by you.

> The data was retrieved and analyzed on Google Cloud Platform(GCP). Any cloud platform (such as Paperspace or AWS) is usable, **as long as a GPU is available**.

Also author of the guide informed that he used `Nvidia Tesla P100` GPU.

> For this project, we used the Nvidia Tesla P100 with 100 GB of storage.

This web app is a food classifier and it is also using `deep-learning-language agnostic`.

> This article details how to create a web and mobile `app image classifier` and is `deep-learning-language agnostic`.

So to run this APP your Virtual Machine need to use [GPU](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus)

> Compute Engine provides graphics processing units (GPUs) that you can add to your virtual machine instances. You can use these GPUs to **accelerate specific workloads on your instances such as machine learning and data processing.**

**How to enable GPU on GCE VM?**

Compute Engine > VM instances > Create VM Instance

Under Machine Configuration tab, you have to expand `CPU platform and GPU`. Later `+ Add GPU` as on screen below.

[image]

**From the drop-down menu choose NVidia Tesla P100.**

[image]

Please keep in mind that some `zones` might not have particular `GPU` but in most of the zones `NVidia Tesla P100` is available.

Also you can check this [GKE docs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/add-gpus) for more details.